# Shift-Insert for pasting unformatted text in Libreoffice

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, paste, libreoffice

I find that both Control-V and Shift-Insert keyboard shortcuts paste formatted text in Libreoffice. This seems to be duplication and a waste of keyboard shortcut. How can I set up so that shift-insert pastes UNformatted text in Libreoffice? Currently, I have to go to `Edit > Paste Special > Unformatted text`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Customize` and the `Keyboard` tab.  Under Functions, select `Edit` from the Category list and `Paste Unformatted Text` from the Function list.

This is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> by default.  Click `Delete` to clear this mapping.

Now, find <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> in the Shortcut Keys and click `Modify`.  Finally, press OK.

[image: paste unformatted]

Comment: Another "shortcut" that is available by default is pasting not into the cell but the formula entry bar or the cell in text edit mode. Just press F2 or double-click on the cell before using the regular Ctrl+V.